# Differentiating the distance formula with respect to time

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How does one apply implicit differentiation to the distance formula with respect to time $t$?

$$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @EDX I thought I'd keep it short and sweet since I don't know much about the topic.

Comment: @EDX I have clearly stated what I don't understand, and asked a simple, clear question.  What could I possibly have tried? This isn't a multistep problem, or one you can approach from different angles. It's not intuitive, it's just something you have to know how to do. My calculus teacher, like every other teacher I've met, doesn't give a damn about students and is taking this opportunity presented by the virus to make us learn everything ourselves. I need instruction. If you can't provide it, stop harassing me. I'm not a new user.

Comment: “Implicit differentiation” doesn’t seem applicable here. Once you’ve decided which variables are on $t$, then just apply the chain rule.

Comment: @amd $x_2, y_1$ are both dependent on time. I'm not sure how to apply chain rule to this.

Comment: Work from the outside in: you’ve got the square root of some function of $t$, i.e., $d=\sqrt{f(t)}$, so $d'= {f'(t)\over2\sqrt{f(t)}}$. $f(t)$ is an expression that involves two different functions of $t$, so apply the chain rule to that, and so on. Eventually you’ll reach $x_2'$ and $y_1'$ at which point the process stops.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I understand your situation, it isn't quite easy !  Because you're not a new user you know that person on that forum like to know what you've tried or what you now about, just to have the impression that they won't do the job entirely for you. This period is easy for no one. Keep on the community is all the more needed when having your kind of teacher. So just remind by the future the make a small sentence to show to other, you're making the job behind, which I don't doubt of you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let introduce

$$ X(t)=(x_1(t)-x_2(t))^2+(y_1(t)-y_2(t))^2$$

Differentiating relatively to $t$:

$$X'(t)=2[(x_1'(t)-x_2'(t))(x_1-x_2)+(y_1'(t)-y_2'(t))(y_1(t)-y_2(t))] $$

So :

$$ d'(t)=\dfrac{X'(t)}{2\sqrt{{X}(t)}}=\dfrac{2[(x_1'(t)-x_2'(t))(x_1(t)-x_2(t))+(y_1'(t)-y_2'(t))(y_1(t)-y_2(t))}{2d(t)} $$

Is that convenient ? If you need more explaination don't hesitate.